# Riak make rel failed application validation with reason: missing_app_file

Tags: macos, riak

I installed riak from github, then ran:

```
make rel
```

And got this:

```
s/node_package failed application validation with reason:
{missing_app_file,"/User/foo/riak/deps/node_package"}.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What branch in the repo are you attempting to build?

Comment: @BrianRoach develop, the default branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default branch is `develop` - it's the development branch and may or may not always build.

You want to checkout the appropriate release tag and build that. The current release is tagged `riak-1.4.6`.

Comment: I checked out riak-1.4.6, did make rel and still got {missing_app_file, "riak/deps/node_package"}.
ERROR: 'get-deps' failed while processing riak: rebar_abort

Comment: What version of erlang are you using?

Comment: And actually ... if you already tried to build develop you may need to delete `deps/` (I generally delete `riak/` and reclone just to make sure there's no cruft)

Comment: git checkout riak-1.4.6, rm -rf deps, make rel worked, thanks! Now if only my servers would start.. (detailed notes): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936642/riak-node-is-not-running