# riak node is not running

Tags: macos, riak

I installed riak version riak-1.4.6.

I ran make rel then make devrel.

```
rel/gen_dev dev1 rel/vars/dev_vars.config.src rel/vars/dev1_vars.config
Generating dev1 - node='dev1@127.0.0.1' pbc=10017 http=10018 handoff=10019
(cd rel && ../rebar generate target_dir=../dev/dev1 overlay_vars=vars/dev1_vars.config)
==> rel (generate)
mkdir -p dev
rel/gen_dev dev2 rel/vars/dev_vars.config.src rel/vars/dev2_vars.config
Generating dev2 - node='dev2@127.0.0.1' pbc=10027 http=10028 handoff=10029
(cd rel && ../rebar generate target_dir=../dev/dev2 overlay_vars=vars/dev2_vars.config)
==> rel (generate)
mkdir -p dev
rel/gen_dev dev3 rel/vars/dev_vars.config.src rel/vars/dev3_vars.config
Generating dev3 - node='dev3@127.0.0.1' pbc=10037 http=10038 handoff=10039
(cd rel && ../rebar generate target_dir=../dev/dev3 overlay_vars=vars/dev3_vars.config)
==> rel (generate)
mkdir -p dev
```

Then I ran

```
./dev/dev1/bin/riak start
!!!!
!!!! WARNING: ulimit -n is 256; 4096 is the recommended minimum.
!!!!:riak username$ ./dev/dev2/bin/riak start
!!!!
!!!! WARNING: ulimit -n is 256; 4096 is the recommended minimum.
!!!!
```

Same for ./dev/dev2/bin/riak start

In my web browser: `http://localhost:10017/stats`

Cannot find server.

I then ran

```
 ./dev/dev2/bin/riak-admin cluster join dev1@127.0.0.1
Node is not running!
```

then

```
 ./dev/dev1/bin/riak restart
Node 'dev1@127.0.0.1' not responding to pings.
```

Ok, so I'll try starting again:

```
./dev/dev1/bin/riak start
!!!!
!!!! WARNING: ulimit -n is 256; 4096 is the recommended minimum.
!!!!
```

This time it restarted:

```
./dev/dev1/bin/riak restart
ok
```

In

```
vim ./dev/dev1/etc/app.config
```

I find

```
 %% Protocol Buffers interface will bind.
        {pb, [ {"127.0.0.1", 10017 } ]}
        ]},
```

and

```
   %% http is a list of IP addresses and TCP ports that the Riak
          %% HTTP interface will bind.
          {http, [ {"127.0.0.1", 10018 } ]},

          %% https is a list of IP addresses and TCP ports that the Riak
          %% HTTPS interface will bind.
          %{https, [{ "127.0.0.1", 10018 }]},
```

But I cannot get a ping from either 127.0.0.1:10017 or 127.0.0.1:10018.

```
./dev/dev1/etc/vm.args
```

shows

```
## Name of the riak node
-name dev1@127.0.0.1
```

How do I start these riak servers?

Comment: Anything in the logs that is jumping out as being bad (`./dev/devX/logs`)? You should just be able to start the nodes (though upping the ulimit is a good idea)

Comment: Also - what version of erlang is installed, and how was it installed?

Comment: Crash.log: 014-01-05 11:01:51 =CRASH REPORT====
  crasher:
    initial call: riak_kv_index_hashtree:init/1
    pid: <0.1462.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {{{badmatch,{error,{db_open,"IO error: ./data/anti_entropy/1233142006497949337234359077604363797834693083136/000002.dbtmp: Too many open files"}}}

Comment: Error.log: 2014-01-05 11:01:51.099 [error] <0.1462.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.1462.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: no match of right hand value {error,{db_open,"IO error: ./data/anti_entropy/1233142006497949337234359077604363797834693083136

Comment: Erlang version, installed with homebrew yesterday: erlang: stable R16B03 (bottled), HEAD

Comment: Looking up the first crash, looks like that might be memory related?

Comment: "Too many open files" is a ulimit issue, which is why it warns to increase it to 4096. Also, for 1.4.6 you want to use Erlang R15B01.

Comment: when I type 'ulimit' in my console, I see "unlimited". I did brew uninstall erlang and am now attempting to install R15B01.

Comment: The output of ulimit with no options is not related to what the giant warning is telling you ;)

Comment: Apologies.. forgot to update. Thank you I set ulimit -n 4096 then ran the server after re-installing the correct Erlang version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Riak is fairly picky about what version of Erlang should be installed. From [its documentation on that](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/building/installing/erlang/), it looks like R15B01 is the version of Erlang you need installing.

Also, I'd advise you to find binaries or packages for the platform of your choice, rather than building from source.

Comment: I brew uninstalled erlang, installed via http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/building/installing/erlang/, erased the log folder, set ulimit -n to 4096, restarted the server. Now I have empty error.log and crash.log, erlang.log, run_erl.log all indicate a server starting, but I still cannot view http://localhost:10017/stats .

Comment: console.log:<0.163.0>@riak_core_capability:process_capability_changes:530 New capability: {riak_control,member_info_version} = v1
2014-01-05 20:17:06.080 [info] <0.7.0> Application riak_control started on node 'dev1@127.0.0.1'
2014-01-05 20:17:06.080 [info] <0.7.0> Application erlydtl started on node 'dev1@127.0.0.1'
2014-01-05 20:17:19.199 [info] <0.322.0>@riak_core:wait_for_service:464 Wait complete for service riak_kv (13 seconds)

Comment: I am attempting the riak binary install. I went with the source because the book I am reading recommended building the source to get the dev[1-3] servers

Comment: 10017 is the *protocol buffers* port. 10018 is the http port